# Can't start ubuntu on Vaio Z

Tags: 10.10, boot, vaio

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 32bit on [this pc](http://www.sonystyle.com.hk/products/apps/product/simplePage.do?modelCode=27533387&lang=en).
I have both tried with Wubi from Windows and from USB stick, but after the installation process when I select to boot Ubuntu the screen becomes black and nothing happens (btw I can hear the cpu running)!

Notice that maybe it is something related to the graphic card of the pc, since when I use Ubuntu in live mode or during the installation process all the graphics and colors are messed up as if there wasn't an appropriate diriver...

What can I do??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your System Uses Optimus Graphic's so that it can switch between 2 different GPU's one Nvidia one Intel. Ubuntu and linux in general don't support GPU switching yet.

To get Ubuntu running on your machine you will need to disable one or the other GPU's in the bios then reinstall Ubuntu. Or change your grub to boot with `nomodeset`

to do this you need to open grub you can do this from the live cd

typing `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in a terminal will open the grub config obviously you will need to modify this to line to where your Ubuntu is installed.

then find this line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and replace it with

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

save and close and reboot

there is a detailed guide to alternate boot options [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) in the Ubuntu Forums

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Press 'e' at the GRUB screen

Scroll down to the line which reads 'quiet splash', delete this and type in 'nomodeset' in their place.

Now press `Ctrl + X` to reboot

You should now be able to login as expected.

As you have a Nvidia graphics card you will need to install the restricted drivers, you need to go to System-> Administration-> Hardware drivers, and select and activate the nvidia current driver.

Once the driver has been downloaded and activated you will be prompted to reboot.